# Is there a way to see a list of members of a Trello board?

Tags: trello

All I can see is how to add new members, but not current members. I am sure I am missing something. Any pointers?

Answer (score 5):

From the right menu, under **Board**, click on **Options** → **Members...**

[image]

Comment: I don't see the options menu. I'm unable to leave a board to which I was invited.

Comment: @IanGarmaise, do you see the right-side menu column?